# How to make URI versioning optional in a nestjs REST application

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

NestJS URI Versioning for HTTP REST applications can be easily enabled when following the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning).

The docs do however not explain how to make URI versioning optional.

**Example:**

`/api/v1/users`

`/api/v2/users`

`/api/users` -> should be mapped to v1 to allow existing webhooks to keep working

**Question:**

How can we make the URI versioning optional in a NestJS REST application so that old versions (without any api version) keep working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `VERSION_NEUTRAL` version on `defaultVersion` option like:

```js
app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    defaultVersion: [VERSION_NEUTRAL, '1', '2'],
});
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning

Comment: I didn't added this on the docs site because the type defs of `defaultVersion` should tell you can achieve that btw

Comment: Is there a way we can check if the versioning enabled or not? @MicaelLevi

Comment: @Raj I guess the only way is by looking at the logs. You'll see `(version: x)`

Comment: @MicaelLevi I meant I have to check this in code. I have to handle one scenario on the basis of enabled version.

Comment: This strategy doesn't seem to be allowed. It either accepts `VERSION_NEUTRAL` (a symbol), a version string, or an array of version strings. Not a combination of version strings and a symbol.

Comment: it is in the latest version. You always can inspect the source: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/61b11ad31506778500ad15c82f94a62774a68000/packages/common/interfaces/version-options.interface.ts#L80

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The following is a hack and results in the global prefix for URI versioning no longer working, please use the accepted answer.

**Original Answer:**

To make versioning optional, set the versioning prefix to an empty string (default is `v`) and set the versioning string including the prefix explicitly.

In `main.ts`:

```
app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    defaultVersion: ['', 'v1', 'v2'],
    prefix: '',
});
```

In the v1 controller:

`@Controller({ path: 'users', version: ['v1', ''] })`

Comment: this is the hacky way